# collection was modified enumeration operation might not execute with foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, datatable, datarow

`DataRow.Delete()` is working fine in one method but not working in another method.

```
//Working method
public static bool finalThrustHDForce(int startPoint, int nPlotSelection)
{
    int startVal = 1;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtThrustCalc.Rows)
        {
            if ((startVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength]) - startPoint) < 0)
                dr.Delete();
            else
                dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength] = startVal;
        }
        dtThrustCalc.AcceptChanges();
        calculateBreadkDown();
        calculateCriticalPoints(nPlotSelection);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.Log(); return false; }
    return true;
}
// not working , getting error collection was modified enumeration operation //might not execute
```

Comment: Please share the code of method in which delete not working

Comment: Does using `foreach (DataRow dr in dtThrustCalc.Rows.ToList())` help?

Comment: @mjwills Yes it works but it creates a copy of the data rows which could be arbitrarily large and end up consuming the target system's resources.

Comment: `it creates a copy of the data rows` You mean it creates a copy of the **references** to the data rows. Which are almost certainly very small.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the collection of things that you are iterating through using foreach has been modified within that loop. Consider not deleting it at that point, and making a list of things to delete. Then delete those things after the foreach has finished.

Comment: Or replace the `foreach` loop with simple `for`.

Comment: @mmushtaq - "simple" `for`. Most people working at this level will replace the `foreach` with a simple `for` and end up writing the oft-repeated bug wherein they still increment the index after performing a delete and so end up skipping some elements. Writing the `for` *correctly* needs thought and consideration.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever And storing DataRows which are going to be deleted in separate List, is also going to consume memory and it also needs to implement extra lines of code and logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the problem with skipping elements is easily addressed by using a reverse `for` loop as I demonstrate in my answer.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie - yes, that's one solution. I was just objecting to a throwaway "simple" `for` being suggested as an adequate replacement.

Comment: @mmushtaq The memory overhead is not that big... The new list is only a collection of references to the objects - the objects themselves are not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

**The Cause**

You're getting that message because to enumerate a collection using `foreach` requires that the collection does not get changed (i.e.  no addition or removal of elements) until the enumeration is completed. By deleting a data row from the collection, you violate this requirement and hence the error.

**The Solution**

Create a list of items to be deleted and then delete them after having done the first iteration.

```
var toDelete = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow dr in dtThrustCalc.Rows)
{
    if ((startVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength]) - startPoint) < 0)
        toDelete.Add(dr);
    else
        dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength] = startVal;
}

foreach (var dr in toDelete)
    dtThrustCalc.Rows.Remove(dr); // not so sure of this as I'm using my phone
```

This method uses a bit more memory to store a cache of the items to be deleted.

The alternative is to use a reverse `for` loop and delete the items as you encounter them.

```
for (var i = dtThrustCalc.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var dr = dtThrustCalc[i];
    if ((startVal = Convert.ToInt32(dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength]) - startPoint) < 0)
        dr.Delete();
    else
        dr[ThrustCalculation.pathLength] = startVal;
}
```

By traversing the collection in reverse, you're assured that you'll not skip any items even when you remove some items midstream.